# Pseudocode or resources to create tables and graphs using Python and Postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I am looking for a recommendations (and possible pseudocode) on either the proper process to follow to get started on a project or a direction on resources where I can go to learn more.

I am new to Python and have a need to take queries from a database and convert them to tables and graphs either online or in print.

Requirements:

- The code must be in Python
- I need to connect the code to a PostgreSQL database
- Data from the queries must be aggregated (grouped by), cased and
  counted (preferably outside of the database so generic queries are
  reusable)
- Final products must be presented in graphs and tables

I believe what I need to do is:

1. Connect to the database using an adaptor such as "Psychopg" (this is done)
2. Pass connection data and queries to the Postgres database (this is done)
3. Manipulate and present the data using a library or
       module?(this is where I am stuck - see below)

Writing loops etc. to iterate through all the queries seems like it would be grossly inefficient.  From what I have read searching online through sites such as datacamp.org and the official library documentation, it looks like what I need to do is use a library such as Pandas, put the results into a dataframe then use another library to "Plot" the results.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me if I am on the right track and guide me towards any additional libraries that may help or any examples that may exist online I could look at to "test" and aid in the learning process.

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely on the right track with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), and there is plotting built into Pandas too. Not knowing exactly what kind of plotting you need, [here is an example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html). Here is a [good article about plotting in Pandas](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/understand-df-plot-in-pandas/), by no means comprehensive but a good starting point.

A more comprehensive documentation of Pandas plot library is Matplotlib which is what Pandas uses. Matplotlib has a [great intro here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html).

Another library that might help you is Seaborn, a popular library to visualize large amounts of data. [Good article to get you started with seaborn](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2017/03/16/pandas-seaborn-a-guide-to-handle-visualize-data-elegantly/). [Seaborn also has some tutorials on their websit](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial.html)e for visualizing different types of data. So I'd recommend checking that out too.